# Display multiple String items Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a last Java homework task, this task is about employees,
my method should print employee's names and surnames, worked more than "n" years.

What I've done for now:

```
    public class LastTask {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee employee1 = new Employee("Dobrobaba", "Irina", "Ivanovna",
                "Moskva", 1900, 6);
        Employee employee2 = new Employee("Shmal", "Anna", "Nikolaevna",
                "Krasnodar", 2017, 8);
        Employee employee3 = new Employee("Kerimova", "Niseimhalum", "Magomedmirzaevna",
                "New-York", 2010, 3);
        Employee employee4 = new Employee("Dobryden", "Yuri", "Viktorovich",
                "Auckland", 2000, 11);
        Employee employee5 = new Employee("Lopata", "Leonid", "Nikolaevich",
                "Beijing", 2014, 11);
    }

    /**
     * Prints employees' information, which have worked more than 'n' year(s) for now.
     *
     * @param n years quantity
     * @return the String, contained surname, name, patronymic and address of the specific employee(s).
     */
    public static String displayEmployees(int n) {

        return null;
    }
}

class Employee {
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String patronymic;
    private String address;
    private int employmentYear;
    private int employmentMonth;


    Employee(String surname, String name, String patronymic, String address, int employmentYear, int employmentMonth) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.address = address;
        this.employmentYear = employmentYear;
        this.employmentMonth = employmentMonth;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPatronymic() {
        return patronymic;
    }

    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) {
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getEmploymentYear() {
        return employmentYear;
    }

    public void setEmploymentYear(int employmentYear) {
        this.employmentYear = employmentYear;
    }

    public int getEmploymentMonth() {
        return employmentMonth;
    }

    public void setEmploymentMonth(int employmentMonth) {
        this.employmentMonth = employmentMonth;
    }
}
```

I made a parametrised constructor for creating employees with multiple parameters, also made parameters encapsulated.
Have no clue what to do next, task says that I can use List/ArrayList, but after some time googling about it, I still can't understand how to implement a condition like `if (employmentYear - currentYear >= n) then return employee1, employee4` for example.
Could you give me some tips?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Make array of `Employee` class objects and use `for-loop`.

Comment: You can do something like add employees to a list; traverse the list; check the condition of each employee: if the condition matches, print the name of his/hers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `static ArrayList` and add those all employees to that `ArrayList`, and in `displayEmployees` method you can stream that list based on condition `if employee EmploymentYear greater than n print details and add to another list` so finally if you want you can just return count of employees or you can return List of employees also

```
public class LastTask {

 static List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee employee1 = new Employee("Dobrobaba", "Irina", "Ivanovna",
            "Moskva", 1900, 6);
    Employee employee2 = new Employee("Shmal", "Anna", "Nikolaevna",
            "Krasnodar", 2017, 8);
    Employee employee3 = new Employee("Kerimova", "Niseimhalum", "Magomedmirzaevna",
            "New-York", 2010, 3);
    Employee employee4 = new Employee("Dobryden", "Yuri", "Viktorovich",
            "Auckland", 2000, 11);
    Employee employee5 = new Employee("Lopata", "Leonid", "Nikolaevich",
            "Beijing", 2014, 11);

    employee.add(employee1);
    employee.add(employee2);
    employee.add(employee3);
    employee.add(employee4);
    employee.add(employee5);
}

/**
 * Prints employees' information, which have worked more than 'n' year(s) for now.
 *
 * @param n years quantity
 * @return the String, contained surname, name, patronymic and address of the specific employee(s).
 */
public static int displayEmployees(int n) {
    List<Employee> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    employee.stream().forEach(emp->{
        if(emp.getEmploymentYear()-Year.now().getValue()>=n) {
            System.out.println("Employee Name : "+emp.getName()+" Sur Aame : "+emp.getSurname());
             finalList.add(emp);
        }
    });

    return finalList.size();
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer! I also have to write tests,
like `private static void displayEmployeesTest() {
        assertEquals("displayEmployeesTest", "name  surname", displayEmployees(3));
    }`
How can I make the method displayEmployees returning "String" or "String[]" ?

Comment: what tests yo mean?

Comment: why do you want to return `String` or `String[]` just return `Employee` object or `List` you can get name and surname by using getters right>?

Comment: i think for test case you will return one object, so return one employee object and from that get name and surname

Comment: but it seems like I need to test the whole result, I mean to test if all required employees are defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178265/discussion-between-deadpool-and-artshakhov).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to find *"worked more than 'n' years"*, this might help you.

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - employmentYear >= n
```

Comment: @artshakhov my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a proper `toString()` method in the Employee class to get the desired output, apart from that I have used the `filter()` method from the Stream object to filter through the Employee objects. I am passing the number of years worked as an input parameter and calculating the years served in employment from the `employmentYear` field.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LastTask {
    private  static List<Employee>  listEmps;
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Employee employee1 = new Employee("Dobrobaba", "Irina", "Ivanovna",
                "Moskva", 1900, 6);
        Employee employee2 = new Employee("Shmal", "Anna", "Nikolaevna",
                "Krasnodar", 2017, 8);
        Employee employee3 = new Employee("Kerimova", "Niseimhalum", "Magomedmirzaevna",
                "New-York", 2010, 3);
        Employee employee4 = new Employee("Dobryden", "Yuri", "Viktorovich",
                "Auckland", 2000, 11);
        Employee employee5 = new Employee("Lopata", "Leonid", "Nikolaevich",
                "Beijing", 2014, 11);

        listEmps = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(employee1,employee2,employee3,employee4,employee5));
        //display employee details of employees who worked more than 17 years.
        displayEmployees(17);
    }

    /**
     * Prints employees' information, which have worked more than 'n' year(s) for now.
     *
     * @param n years quantity
     * @return the String, contained surname, name, patronymic and address of the specific employee(s).
     */
   public static void displayEmployees(int n) {
    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    listEmps.stream()
            .filter(emp ->{
                         return year - emp.getEmploymentYear() > n;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

class Employee {
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String patronymic;
    private String address;
    private int employmentYear;
    private int employmentMonth;


    Employee(String surname, String name, String patronymic, String address, int employmentYear, int employmentMonth) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.address = address;
        this.employmentYear = employmentYear;
        this.employmentMonth = employmentMonth;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPatronymic() {
        return patronymic;
    }

    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) {
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getEmploymentYear() {
        return employmentYear;
    }

    public void setEmploymentYear(int employmentYear) {
        this.employmentYear = employmentYear;
    }

    public int getEmploymentMonth() {
        return employmentMonth;
    }

    public void setEmploymentMonth(int employmentMonth) {
        this.employmentMonth = employmentMonth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Employee details: " + this.name + this.surname + this.address + this.employmentYear;
    }
}
```